# Read compiled information during runtime with java

Tags: java

is it possible to get the compiler information (java version and 32 or 64 bit) of a compiled class during runtime? I know it is possible within the command line for a jar file, but is that also possible during runtime?

I want to create a log entry during startup of my application with those information.

Thanks
Hauke

Comment: " I know it is possible within the command line for a jar file" <-- can you edit your question and show what command you use and its output?

Comment: your question doesn't make sense, as the compiled class is the same for 32 bit and 64 bit. What you can determine runtime is the JVM information, which can be 32 bit or 64 bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a version of compiler but byte code - but might be useful:

Every **.class** file you generate **contains a version's stamp**: two unsigned short integers starting at byte offset 4, right after the 0xCAFEBABE magic number.
They are the major/minor version numbers of the class format.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        String className = MyClass.class.getName();
        String classAsPath = className.replace('.', '/') + ".class";
        InputStream stream = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(classAsPath);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8];
        int r = stream.read(buffer);
        if (r < 8) {
            throw new IOException("Something wrong we could read only " + r + " bytes");
        }
        int major = buffer[6];
        int minor = buffer[7];
        int version = (major << 8);
        version = version | minor;
        System.out.printf("Version (major %X, minor %X) -> %X", major, minor, version);
    }
}
```

Then you map the byte code version to JDK version:

- J2SE 7 = 51 (0x33 hex)
- J2SE 6.0 = 50 (0x32 hex)
- J2SE 5.0 = 49 (0x31 hex)
- JDK 1.4 = 48 (0x30 hex)
- JDK 1.3 = 47 (0x2F hex)
- JDK 1.2 = 46 (0x2E hex)
- JDK 1.1 = 45 (0x2D hex)

Comment: This only gives the bytecode version though, not information about the compiler

Answer (score 1):

A compiled class is not "32 or 64 bit".

The bytecode is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom annotation with runtime retention. Check this for example: [Java 1.5.0.12 and custom Annotations at Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714484/java-1-5-0-12-and-custom-annotations-at-runtime)